# Equivalent of Session.Abandon() in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Is there an equivalent of `Session.Abandon()` in Windows Phone 8?

For instance, in order to create a "session" in Windows Phone, one would do the following:

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["Username"] = username;
```

Now, I can simply destroy its value using:

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["Username"] = null;
```

However, if I have multiple "sessions", I would have to do this for each and every one of them.  Is there a method which destroys all the "sessions" in Windows Phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this? `State` is an IDictionary and should support this method.

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.State.Clear();
```